# Iterating through a vector of names using for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

```
library(sjPlot)
```

I am using sjPlot to create quick xtabs:

```
sjPlot::tab_xtab(var.row = mtcars$mpg ,var.col =mtcars$wt ,show.row.prc = TRUE)
```

But since I am running it over many cols, I want to set up a loop:

```
    cols <- names(mtcars)
    for (i in cols) {
    
      sjPlot::tab_xtab(
        var.row =  mtcars$mpg,
        var.col = mtcars$i,
        show.row.prc = TRUE
      )
}
```

But this throws an error:

```
Error in table(x_full, grp_full) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

Why is this happening, and can someone please explain subsetting through iteration, or point me to a good resource?

**FYI ---**
This does not return anything.

```
for (i in cols) {
  i <- 'cyl'
  
  sjPlot::tab_xtab(
    var.row =  mtcars$mpg,
    var.col = mtcars[[i]],
    show.row.prc = TRUE
  )
  
}
```

But this does return the chart for mpg - cyl:

```
for (i in cols) {

  sjPlot::tab_xtab(
    var.row =  mtcars$mpg,
    var.col = mtcars$cyl,
    show.row.prc = TRUE
  )
  
}
```

Comment: Try: `var.col = mtcar[[i]]`

Comment: When you get an error, part of the debugging process is to check each of the arguments to see if they look like you expect. `mtcars$mpg` will be fine, but `mtcars$i` will be `NULL`, almost certainly not what you expect. As @Dave2e said, the way to access the column indirectly where the column *name* is in `i`, you must use [`[` or `[[`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html), depending on if you want a `list` or `vector` returned (likely the second).

Comment: @Dave2e Thanks, I don't know about you, but when I run it, I don't see any output in the viewer, do you?

Comment: I did not run the code, but I suspect you need to explicitly call out a `print()` statement inside the loop.  Wrap a print around the `tab_xtab` call.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, this is the solution, but still looking for some understanding. Why mtcars[[i]] instead of mtars[i]? Why doesn't mrcars$i work?

```
for (i in cols) {

  plt <- sjPlot::tab_xtab(
    var.row =  mtcars$mpg,
    var.col = mtcars[[i]],
    show.row.prc = TRUE
  )
  print(plt)
  
}
```

Comment: mtcars$i  - is looking for a column named i. mtcars[i] is the value stored at index i, where the index is an integer. and mtcars[[i]] is column named with the value stored in i.