# R: using the index inside a for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, indexing

I was wondering how I can use the index (i) of a "for loop" inside it. Especially with the "$-notation".

```
for (i in tickers){
 
  getSymbols(i, from = '2021-01-6',
             to = "2021-10-21",warnings = FALSE,
             auto.assign = TRUE)

  MA9 = mean(tail(i$i.Adjusted, n=9))
  
  print(MA9)
}
```

Thanks already for taking your time to read this!

Comment: See this question and read the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69587569/iterating-through-a-vector-of-names-using-for-loop-in-r/69587821#comment122999547_69587821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSymbols` function works for multiple tickers at the same time. You can use `mget` to get them in a list and since `Adjusted` value is the 6th column you can subset it and get the mean of last 9 values with `sapply`.

Here is an example with tickers `c('QQQ','SPY')`.

```
library(quantmod)
tickers <- c('QQQ','SPY')

getSymbols(tickers, from = '2021-01-6',
           to = "2021-10-21",warnings = FALSE,
           auto.assign = TRUE)

sapply(mget(tickers), function(x) mean(tail(x[, 6], n=9)))

#    QQQ      SPY 
#366.1511 442.2178
```